# litstudy Package Installation Python

Tags: python, visual-studio, python-packaging, citations

I am Trying to do Co-Citation Network analysis and have to install package called "litstudy" in Python but I am getting an Error installing it in Jupyter and Python 3.10

Link for litstudy package https://nlesc.github.io/litstudy/index.html

**In Python 3.10 while installing from Command Prompt getting Error**

`C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.32.31326\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2 [end of output] note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip. error: legacy-install-failure`

**It Gets installed in Jupyter but when I import the package I get error**

```
 import litstudy   
 Traceback (most recent call last):

 File "C:\Users\vibhu\AppData\Local\Programs\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3437, in run_code
exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)

File "<ipython-input-2-b5a65b8eaed7>", line 1, in <module>
import litstudy

File "C:\Users\vibhu\AppData\Local\Programs\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\lib\site-packages\litstudy\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
from .sources import *  # noqa: F403,F401


  File "C:\Users\vibhu\AppData\Local\Programs\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\lib\site-packages\litstudy\sources\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
from .scopus import search_scopus, refine_scopus, fetch_scopus

 File "C:\Users\vibhu\AppData\Local\Programs\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\lib\site-packages\litstudy\sources\scopus.py", line 236
if doi := id.doi:
```

If anyone can Solve this for me i will be really grateful I'm stuck on this for amost a day and need to get started with networking analysis or if you have any other solution like this for Citation Networking

Comment: You seem to have left out part of the error. Can you edit the complete stack trace into your question?

Comment: @joanis updated the error stack
Pls see if you can find anything

Comment: Looks to me like the failure happened while compiling the module. That error message from pip is critical, it basically means the compiled parts of the module didn't get installed correctly. I'm not familiar with that module, but we'll need some more information: most importantly how is Python installed? Conda or Python for Windows or something else? If not Conda, I'd recommend trying with Conda, it often handles things better.

Comment: Running `pip install litstudy`, and wow, that thing has a huge number of dependencies. Some just failed on my Win10 machine too, in my conda environment. That thing could really use pre-built wheels! In my case, it's the dependencies `fa2` and `wordcloud` that fail to compile.

Comment: For wordcloud, it looks like even the official build is failling: https://pypi.org/project/wordcloud/1.8.1/ but `conda install -c conda-forge wordcloud` is more likely to work if the authors published pre-compiled packages to conda.

Comment: For fa2, I tried `conda install -c conda-forge fa2` and I eventually got this message: fa2 -> `python[version='>=3.6,<3.7.0a0|>=3.7,<3.8.0a0|>=3.8,<3.9.0a0|>=3.9,<3.10.0a0']` which means that it just won't work with Python 3.10 (yet). It looks like you'll have to downgrade to Python <= 3.9.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

##### TL;DR

- Dependencies of the litstudy package are not compatible with Python 3.10, you will have to downgrade to 3.9
- Install packages from conda-forge, using conda, so you don't have to compile them.

##### The long story

The `litstudy` package has a huge number of dependencies, several of which need to be compiled. The error message you got indicates that compilation failed for some one them.

The dependencies `wordcloud` and `fa2` where a problem on my computer when I ran `pip install litstudy` to reproduce your problem.

For `wordcloud`, the exists a pre-compiled Conda bundle for it, available from `conda-forge`. I recommend using conda (Anaconda3 or Miniconda3, either will do).

This worked for wordcloud, as recommended by its own [readme](https://pypi.org/project/wordcloud/1.8.1/):

```
conda install -c conda-forge wordcloud
```

For `fa2`, there was a second problem: when I ran `conda install -c conda-forge fa2`, I got this message:

```
UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found
to be incompatible with the existing python installation in your environment:

Specifications:

  - fa2 -> python[version='>=3.6,<3.7.0a0|>=3.7,<3.8.0a0|>=3.8,<3.9.0a0|>=3.9,<3.10.0a0']

Your python: python==3.10.4
```

which basically says `fa2` is not compatible (yet) with Python 3.10. So, you will have to downgrade to a 3.9.x version of Python to use this package.

So to install `litstudy` and its dependencies, I just created a Python 3.9.12 environment using conda, and then I was able to install everything.

##### The cut-and-pastable solution

Putting it all together, this worked for me, after installing Miniconda3:

```
conda create -n py39 python==3.9.12
conda activate py39
conda install -c conda-forge fa2 wordcloud
pip install litstudy
```

In that environment, `import litstudy` works fine.

Comment: My general experience, especially on Windows, is that if you can rely on the authors to have pre-compiled a package for you, things work much more smoothly.

Comment: Thank you so much, helped me get started with it..